# Change Password PHP/Ajax/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a form for changing a users password. No errors are being generated in the console but nothing is being updated. The validation side is also working so it must be down to the Ajax part?

Disclaimer: I know I shouldn't be using mysql in PHP, but I'm trying to get the basics down and will learn mysqli at a later date :)
Also, config.php is used in multiple other functions so I know config.php is fine.

Any idea what is going wrong?

HTML:

```
            <fieldset>
                <form method="post" name="password-form" id="form-password">
                <label>Password:</label> <br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" size="32" />
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Re-Enter Password:</label> <br>
                <input type="password" name="password-check" id="password-check" value="" size="32" />
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="passsubmit">
                </form>
            </fieldset>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
        $("#passsubmit").click(function(){
        $(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false;
        var newpass = $("#password").val();
        var checkVal = $("#password-check").val();
        if (newpass == '') {
            $("#password").after('<span class="error">Please enter a password.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if (checkVal == '') {
            $("#password-check").after('<span class="error">Please re-enter your password.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if (newpass != checkVal ) {
            $("#password-check").after('<span class="error">Passwords do not match.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }

        if(hasError == true) {return false;}

        if(hasError == false) {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resource/changepassword.php",
                data: {newpass:newpass},
                success: function(){}
                });
        };
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$newpass=$_POST['newpass'];
$sql_rec = "select UserID from useradmin where username='$user_check' ";
$rs_rec = mysql_query($sql_rec);
$data_rec = mysql_fetch_object($rs_rec);

$userID = $data_rec->UserID; 



$updatesql="UPDATE useradmin SET passcode='$newpass' WHERE UserID=$userID";

mysql_query($updatesql, $bd) or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

$bd is my MySQL connection details from config.php.

UPDATE:

I've added `<div id="passsubmit2">123</div>` to my page and changed the jquery to:

```
$(function(){
        $("#passsubmit2").click(function(){
```

And it works perfectly, so it's only when using the form button that it doesn't work?

Comment: You're creating a query for the update, but never actually executing it. Further, the argument you'd be sending to the query is the text of the query you use to extract the user id, not the extracted id itself. I don't understand why you're extracting the id first - why not just update on the basis of the username?

Comment: Erm, I don't know really. I come from a heavy MS SQL background and was always taught to do everything from UIDs rather than anything else. I guess it's just how I've always done SQL side things. Will make some changes to the above script based on what I've changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

I needed to add `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the normal form submit from firing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending form data to your server through an Ajax request, you dont need that input of submit type at first place, because this will try to submit the form on click and you will have to write additional code for stopping the default functionality of that submit button. So replace that submit button with simple html button or a link.

Answer (score 0):

change your data inside ajax to

```
if(hasError == false) {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resource/changepassword.php",
                data: {
                    newpass : newpass,
                },
                success: function(){}
                });
  };
```

because you are not sent the data to server and info variable not declared

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass all the required `data` to the PHP server. Right now, from what I can see, you are passing an empty variable.

```
info={
newpass : newpass,
checkVal: checkVal
};

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resource/changepassword.php",
                data: info,
                success: function(response){
                  console.log(response);
                }
      });
```

On the PHP side:

```
<?php
$newPassword=$_POST['newpass '];
```

EDIT: Going a bit further with this, you really want to store a user ID (unique numeric ID) in the session rather then the username. Referencing through-out your mysql DB using the username as a unique value is a very poor idea (trust me, I made the same mistake).

Also, you should require users to enter their old password whenever changing a current password (what if they left the website up on their computer).

Comment: Good point on the userID. Makes perfect sense. Why change to $newPassword ? Have updated my script above, realised I wasn't actually passing the new password through... doh.

Comment: Sorry, was just putting down a simple example, did not realize you already had that part of the PHP. The variable name doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah ok I see. I've update the script to include the `newpass` variable (I don't actually need `checkVal`) however still no updates being made.

Comment: Try changing `data: newpass,` to `data: {newpass:newpass},`

Comment: still nothing unfortunately :(

Comment: Also, sorry just seen your extra comment. Yes once I get the actual update working, I plan to add the 'Old Password' check.